# Autoinstall Ubuntu 22.04 in Air Gapped network

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, autoinstall

I’m wondering if anyone can point me in some direction. In our environment, we support a high number of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktops all in an air-gapped network. We have a mirror of the Ubuntu repositories in the air-gapped network that allows us to perform updates and installs of other packages in the repo.

Over the past months I’ve been working to migrate our PXE imaging process from the legacy pre-seed (d-i) method over to the newer autoinstall (subiquity) method. Those familiar with the process will know that it’s meant that moving from the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop ISO to the Ubuntu 20.04 Server ISO. This change really didn’t affect us too much as we were able to install the apt package ubuntu-desktop in the autoinstall section of the user-data file.

Now, fast forwarding to getting this to work with Ubuntu 22.04, the first problem I’m running into is a crash during the autoinstall process when trying to install ubuntu-desktop-minimal because it can’t install the firefox snap. I am sure that there’s going to be a few more snap related bumps because I’m on an air-gapped network, but I figured I’d go ahead and ask to see if anyone else already has a solution to this problem?

Some thoughts I had was looking into if it’s possible to download the snaps and populate them somewhere on the local install through an early-command wget or something of that nature. I’ve also thought that maybe I’d have better luck dealing with the ubuntu-desktop install during the cloud-init install phase and handle it through an ansible-pull playbook.  In either case I'm wondering what options are available to be able to autoinstall ubuntu-desktop package using the Ubuntu 22.04 Server ISO in an air-gapped network and not be tripped up by the Firefox Snap package?

Any thoughts or directions are truly appreciated.

Comment: I've not experimented or used the autoinstall options for the `subiquity` or `ubuntu-desktop-installer` so I can't offer any help there; but I've read blogs from Alan Pope (*popey*) on downloading *snap* packages for later install (*inc. on multiple devices; Alan wrote a number of articles on snaps after he left Canonical; being a Ubuntu Member they also appeared on Planet Ubuntu*), how or if that download can be used in your autoinstall though I no details sorry.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc.  I'll check Alan's posts out.  I am hoping that I can find a way to take the downloaded snap/assert and drop it in a local "cache" directory so that when it goes to look for that package it finds it... but something tells me that snapd is built to always communicate with the snapcraft api for snap packages.  Anyways thanks for the ideas... I'm off to do more research!

Comment: there were a number, eg. https://popey.com/blog/2020/12/snap-tips/  (though I found that searching thru UWN; ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue663 using "*site:wiki.ubuntu.com ubuntu weekly newsletter alan pope snap*")

Comment: See the Snap Store Proxy, which includes offline for air-gapped networks: https://docs.ubuntu.com/snap-store-proxy/en/

Comment: Thanks for the link @user535733 .  I admit I was trying to avoid setting up licensing the systems with Ubuntu Pro licenses and setting up additional infrastructure for the sake of a single snap package.  Either way thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

22.04.3 has a subiquity offline install flag, try that, I install servers in an air gapped env, so this has been a good improvement for us, I add our internal repos via post config mgmt tool, but this helps stop the installer bombing out randomly for package or repo related curtin issues

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    fallback: offline-install
```